# Displaying part of a spritesheet in an Android ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, sprite

In Android, is there a **clean** way to display only a given part of a bitmap in an ImageView (for example a single sprite of a sprite sheet), without having to :

- Manually split the bitmap png into small pngs (=> more drawables embedded in the app, tedious manual operation possibly leading to bugs, or loose the spritesheet).
- Have small pngs used in the ImageViews, with the sprite sheet being generated (=> complicated)
- Create "dirty" subclasses for ImageView, Drawable, etc (=> the more we use Android API "ASIS" the better)
- Programmatically create sub-bitmaps of the big bitmap (=> We have to do all the work programmatically)

For instance I have tried creating an ImageView of width/height of 40dp, and setting its drawable as a ClipDrawable displaying only the part of the bitmap I wanted, but it did not go well :

- the clipped part did not fill the parent when using Gravity.CENTER when creating the ClipDrawable.
- The whole "big" PNG was displayed when using Gravity.FILL.

Furthermore this solution is feasable with a simple sprite sheet (for example 2*2 sprites), but I do not think it is possible when using something like a 4*4 sprite sheet. I think ClipDrawable is not meant for such a use.

Isn't there something "clean and easy" like in OpenGL where you can set a texture Id, and set the texture coordinates to display only part of the texture? Considering my researchs I think the best solution is to manually split the big bitmap with Bitmap.createBitmap, when I'd rather ask before starting something like that.

PS : I consider using SpriteSheets because of OpenGl, although my "menus" are developed using Android APIs, hence using ImageView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you familiar with Canvas at all?  I think that is another way that would work for you.

You create one bitmap in memory, then use drawBitmap to draw just the current chunk you want.

Here is a snippet [from the manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint%29):

`public void drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, Rect dst, Paint paint)`

This function ignores the density associated with the bitmap. This is because the source and destination rectangle coordinate spaces are in their respective densities, so must already have the appropriate scaling factor applied.

```
Parameters
bitmap  The bitmap to be drawn
src     May be null. The subset of the bitmap to be drawn
dst     The rectangle that the bitmap will be scaled/translated to fit into
paint   May be null. The paint used to draw the bitmap
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew about canvas but never really used them extensively. This might be a really good solution (my "favorite" one was to programmatically split the bitmaps, but I was afraid this would possibly end up consuming a lot of memory). I will look into that, and as Views use Canvas, this could be handled "automatically" (and using layouts) by creating a custom view drawing only a part of the Bitmap. Thanks again.